# How does Smart weapon tracking work?

Tags: cyberpunk-2077

I have started getting some Smart Weapon archetype drops and as I have the Smart Link hand mod I figured I would try them out.

I can't figure out how to make them work effectively though. They say that you just fire and the projectiles will auto-track to enemies.

However I have had instances where I can fire at an enemy either aiming down sights or hip firing and all the projectiles just seem to fly off in different directions and not strike the intended target. Other instances the projectiles will bend perfectly and get headshots.

What am I missing? How do I know if the Smart weapon is locked onto it's target properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Smart weapon tracking requires that you have the appropriate cyberware installed to integrate with the tracking systems on the weapons. The appropriate mods will have the effect "Allows you to use the smart-targeting module in smart weapons" on the tooltip. You can find these implants at your local ripperdoc.

When using a smart weapon with the appropriate cyberware you get a large rectangular reticule and as long as the enemy you're targeting is in the reticule the bullets fired will curve their trajectory (including around corners and obstacles) to hit the target in all instances except where smart weapon jamming is used. In addition to this, any weak points detected on the enemy will be represented by a small diamond, with the targeted weak point being a filled in diamond. If you have multiple targets in the reticule, the highlighted target is the target that the bullets will head towards.

[image]

As Wakako tells you after you visit to collect your reward for the recovery of Sandra, Tyger Claw's wear tattoos made from dermal ink featuring smart weapon jamming technologies. You'll have a hard time hitting Tygers with a smart weapon whether you use this dermal implant or any of the other smart targeting cyberware.

[image: Tyger Claws block smart targeting]

Comment: Can you add to your answer about how the targeting works?

Comment: While answer makes a good point with respect to Tygers, its not really answering the actual question "How does Smart weapon tracking work?"